# A c++ compiled executable still active in system even after the program end?

Tags: c++

I was trying to code a "Matrix operations" program handling matrices upto 5x5. The first thing to do is take user input for rows and columns, check if it is in range (1 to 5), and if not redo the input process for the faulty values until the correct values are obtained from the user (that's what I coded so far). However, this mundane program managed to startle me when I couldn't recompile an edited script (Permission denied), when I tried to manually delete the executable to force a recompile, windows said Matrix.exe was still open in system.

I rebooted windows and I could recompile once again, several times in fact, but once I run it it's back to square 1. What am I mucking up?

Note: I am using Quincy 2005 for coding as well as compiling.

Note 2: I am not a professional coder please explain accordingly.

Note 3: The code is here ... http://pastebin.com/fArbDsM1

Comment: Kill it in task manager when this happens (or close the program's window...)

Comment: Kill system? is that even possible? Matrix.exe is closed and purged via TM, but when trying to access it again windows denies permission saying it is open in system.

The problem is reset once I reboot though

Comment: Your anti-virus software probably thinks this new exe is suspicious and tries to quarantine it, or something similar. Find a way in AV to make an exception for this particular exe.

Comment: @Dialecticus That could certainly be it... I have avast! and a little google-fu mentioned how avast is a bad AV especially for coding.

Comment: I was just guessing, but if it happens that this is the case I should post a proper answer instead of a comment, so that you can accept it, so that the issue becomes closed. Please let me know if AV was the problem.

Comment: The problem disappeared when I excluded my code directories from avast!'s deepscreen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem myself... Here are the steps that I took...

1. **Switched to code::blocks 16.01 instead of Quincy 2005**: Code::blocks was able to overwrite **Matrix.exe**. Code::blocks didn't show the same problems as Quincy
2. **Switched back to Quincy to reaffirm the problem**: Quincy was able to overwrite only once, i.e. problem not solved.
3. **Excluded the folder containing my codes from AV**: Once I excluded the Codes folder the problem disappeared altogether.

From what I can understand, avast!'s deepscreen is the culprit. Since it loads up my code for scanning I couldn't access or delete the executable in question.

Big thanks to @Dialecticus for suggesting this... Thanks.